# Using the word "write" as a label makes compilation crash

Tags: linguistics, examples, bugs, write, linguex

Took me all night (literally) to figure out.

Compilation was failing one time out of two, with the following original error (line 12) : "Bad space factor (0)".

That was crazy because absolutely nothing in the syntax was making this specific line any different from other similar examples.

I eventually understood that the problem was due to the fact that I was using the word "write" as a label in the previous line (I had somewhat suspected so but initially disregarded the hypothesis as too far-fetched).

The problem is inherent to the internal structure of the \lb(x) command of the package "Philex".

Honestly, people should know about this, because if you are not aware thereof, it is very tricky to find the source of the problem and in any case, you lose so much of your precious time. So this is also why I'm spending time on this post.

The code below compiles fine because I use "Write" instead of "write", but fails otherwise (every other run - PDFtex, Xetex or Luatex).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{philex}

\begin{document}

\lb{wripo}{
\lba{wripoa}{
\lba{writing}{I read all of John's writings.}
\lbz{poem}{I read all of John's poems.}}
\lbz{wripob}{
\lba{Write}{I read all of what John wrote.}  % Using “write” as a label causes compilation failure every other run. => “Bad space factor (0). ...ized}{I read all of what John poetized.}}}”
\lbz{poetized}{\oddity{*}I read all of what John poetized.}}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

So my question is : are there any other words I should avoid as labels, and does there exist a specific method in order to treat "special words" as normal words, i.e. to "escape" their coding properties ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `\label{write}` will eventually create a global macro `\r@write`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is crazy programming.

Comment: Everything is implemented by macros.  Environments are implemented by two macros (e.g. \figure and \endfigure).  Pagestyles (\ps@plain), counter names (\c@page), etc.  Okay, \hypertarget names are sent directly to the PDF, but everything else is given a command name using `\csname ...\endcsname`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `\lba{something}` the `philex` package basically writes out to the aux-file

```
  \gdef\something{\ref{#2}}
```

That means it will break any command with the same name. In your example it broke the primitive `\write` command, but e.g. `\lba{section}` would after two compilations change the output of `\section{Hallo}` to this:

[image]

The problem is mentioned in the documentation in 7 Troubleshooting, which says

> and especially with short labels it sometimes happens that
> a generated label coincides with a control sequence defined by TeX,
> or LaTeX, or some document class or package

This is imho quite an understatement. It is very bad coding to define  commands like this and I wouldn't use a package which does it. But if you have to use it: use labels with a prefix and special chars e.g. `vincent!write?`. The probability of a clash is then much smaller.

Comment: Yes I saw the \gdef problem, wasn't sure was that was about. thank you very much for your clear explanations. Labels are already a headache, but now... I guess using a capital as the first or last character may help.

Comment: Use at least some none-letter like ! or +, that is safer than capitals. And expect other problems, e.g. unwanted spaces.

Comment: Will just stick to Linguex.

Comment: May I suggest that someone creates the tag "Philex" ? It currently doesn't exist and people using that package would certainly find such information useful.