# Understanding some aspects of the philex package

Tags: macros, arguments, linguex, csname

In Philex, you can refer locally to an example (2b) by just typing
\rnx{label} and it will return just (b), otherwise just type \rn{label} and it returns (2b).

Here is the syntax of the two commands:

```
\newcommand{\rf}[2][]{%%
\ifhyperref%%
(\hyperlink{#2}{\csname#2\endcsname}#1)%
\else%%
(\csname#2\endcsname#1)%
\fi}

%Cross-reference to subsentence without main number:%
\newcommand{\rfx}[2][]{%
\ifhyperref%
(\hyperlink{#2}{\csname#2q\endcsname}#1)%
\else%
(\csname#2q\endcsname#1)%
\fi}
```

As you may know, when referring to subsubexamples such as (1a.i), I'm looking for a way to also skip the sublevel and return just (i),

- which is possible thanks to Ulrich Diez's solution as found here:

  - [Any way to reference a particular component of a label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577449/any-way-to-reference-a-particular-component-of-a-label/577464#577464)
- but only works if there is a separator;
- cf. my post here [Local cross-referencing with Linguex/Philex and Cleveref: Skipping 1st and 2nd level sublabels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634519/local-cross-referencing-with-linguex-philex-and-cleveref-skipping-1st-and-2nd-l) ...
- and cf. my larger concern here [Cross-referencing: more sublevels, and presets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637164/cross-referencing-more-sublevels-and-presets).

My question is quite straightforward. I would like to know what \csname#2q actually does, so I can use it to also skip the sublevel label, without having to worry about the presence of a delimiter as in Ulrich's \gobbletodot suggestion.

**Edit**

I found this line :

```
\refstepcounter{altsub}\label{#2q}
```

So this is only a label for the sublevel.

But then we find :

```
\refstepcounter{altsubsub}\label{#2q}
```

So the problem is that #2q is one and the same label for the sub- and subsub- levels.

I guess the way the package is written, I could not refer to the sublabel and only keep the subsublabel.

Comment: Remark, these are *primitive TeX commands* whose documentation/explanation can be found in the TeXbook or TeX by Topic etc..

Comment: `\csname#2q\endcsname` builds a command name, if e.g. #2 is `abc` this would call the command `\abcq`.

Comment: `\csname anything\endcsname` becomes `\anything`.  Adding a `q` makes `\anythingq`.  In both commands, `#1` is the optional (by default empty) argument, and `#2` is the second, mandatory argument.  When you write `\rf{label}` it becomes (if hyperref is not loaded) `(\csname label\endcsname)` which is `(\label)` which seems very weird, since `\label` is a LaTeX command.  `\rfx{label}` then becomes `(\labelq)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. So it's an arbitrary way to call an alternative label, which must be defined higher in the code.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik philex has a quite unsafe method to handle command names, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634309/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ew...

Comment: You mean this is completely crazy... For each label you define (and there are hundreds of them in a thesis), you take the risk of ruining an existing command !...